# Is it okay to answer this question with this information?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I saw [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3038/what-is-the-origin-of-harem-anime) question and it is about the origin of harem genre in anime:

> but how did it start? What is the origin of Harem Anime?

All of the four answers are talking about the anime itself; that how this genre of anime began (as the OP has asked how it started). But none of them is talking about the origin of the name and OP has asked about the origin too.

So my question: Can I answer this question with information about the origin of the name of this genre of anime?

Answer (score 4):

No, personally I don't think it seems appropriate to *just* answer the question with an answer about the origin of the name Harem.  I would imagine an answer just addressing the name may be downvoted.

Why?

A) Most importantly the question isn't about the origin of the name, it's the origin of the genre, of which the name in English (and perhaps other languages) is only a small (and perhaps insignificant) part.  You seem to imply the OP has asked about the name, but I really don't see that in the question.

B) To a lesser degree, as someone who doesn't know the genre but who knows English the name appears self evident.  The dictionary definition of a Harem, together with the description of the genre in the question, I can see why the label has been used.

If there is something interesting about the origin of the name, feel free to add it as additional detail to an answer you write addressing the origin of the genre.  There's no reason here why multiple answers can be provided to the same question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can't I start my answer with something like *You have already received four good answers and one of them is accepted. The only thing I want to add is...*?

Comment: No, you can't.  That's not how this site works.  Every answer should stand alone as a distinct complete answer to the question.  Sometimes we see answers addressing certain perspectives on a question, but they should still stand alone and attempt to address the entire question.

Comment: You are reading into the question that the OP is asking about the name ... but they are not.

Comment: No, I felt the OP wants both. "How the genre started" and "its origin". I thought *its origin* part is asking about the name. Something no one has answered about.

Comment: "What is the origin of Harem Anime?" is not asking about the name.  You would specifically have to say "What is the origin of the name 'Harem Anime'".  They are (perhaps redundantly) restating the question in another way.

Comment: There's a reason why no-one answered that aspect, none of them interpreted that sentence as asking about the name.